# Calling a specific function Code Between Controllers using Services in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory where I keep the code that I want to reuse in various controllers.

When I call the functions on ng-click from each controller respectively its not working.

Also, is there any better way of handling such situations?

view:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-click='hidepop()'>
        <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
            <li>{{user}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nested" ng-click='showpop()' ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.factory("UserService", function ($window) {    
    var root={};
    root.showpop = function () {     
        alert("f")
    }     
    root.hidepop = function () { 
        alert("d")
    }      
    return root;
});

app.controller("AnotherCtrl", function($scope,$location, UserService) {
    $scope.alerter = UserService;        
    $scope.showpop(){
        $scope.alerter.showpop();
    }
    $scope.alerter.hidepop();    
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.alerter = UserService;
    $scope.alerter.showpop();
    $scope.alerter.hidepop();
});
```

here is my fiddle:[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kavinhuh/p8LNR/)

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code a bit to show one way that you could use the service you've started building - http://jsfiddle.net/p8LNR/2/ :

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
            <li>{{user}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nested" ng-click=showpop() ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.factory("UserService", function() {
    var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];
    var root={
        'showpop':function () { 
            alert("f")
        },
        'hidepop':function () { 
            alert("d")
         },
        'users': users
    };
    return root;
});

app.controller("AnotherCtrl", function($scope,$location, UserService) {
    $scope.showpop = function(){
        UserService.showpop();
    }
    $scope.hidepop = function(){
        UserService.hidepop();
    }
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.users = UserService.users
});
```

**Here's some advice on your code:**

- The key advice that I would give you is to step back and remember you're just building javascript, and Angular is just a tool to make your life easier.
- In terms of services specifically, consider a "service" to be a fancy Javascript object that gets created the first time you load it somewhere in code and is persistent.
- It looks like you're getting started building something that will modify the DOM (something named popup), in which case you may actually want to remember that you can do a lot with your html, for example, creating a "pop-up" window with the following:

  ```
  <div ng-style="showpopup">{{ selected_user.name}}</div>
  ```
- If you get really fancy with your code, you should consider building a directive instead: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
- Lastly, and this is a personal preference thing, but I would recommend working on your code formatting, the cleaner and easier to read your code is with proper spacing and indentation, the easier it is to fix things later on. :)